# Elasticsearch Java API implementation to fetch millions of records

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get all doc (millions) in elastic index based on some condition. I used below query in elastic.

```
GET /<index-name>/_search
{
    "from" : 99550, "size" : 500,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "CC_ENGAGEMENT_NUMBER" : "1967" }
    }
}
```

And below are my java implementation.

```
public IndexSearchResult findByStudIdAndcollageId(final String studId, final String collageId,
            Integer Page_Number_Start_Index, Integer Total_No_Of_Records) {
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        List<Map<String, Object>> searchResults = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        IndexSearchResult indexSearchResult = new IndexSearchResult();
        try {
            QueryBuilder qurBd = new BoolQueryBuilder().minimumShouldMatch(2)
                    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("STUD_ID", studId).operator(Operator.AND))
                    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("CLG_ID", collageId).operator(Operator.AND));
            sourceBuilder.from(Page_Number_Start_Index).size(Total_No_Of_Records);
            sourceBuilder.query(qurBd);
            sourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("ROLL_NO.keyword").order(SortOrder.DESC));

            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
            searchRequest.indices("clgindex");
            searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
            SearchResponse response;
            response = rClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            response.getHits().forEach(searchHit -> {
                searchResults.add(searchHit.getSourceAsMap());
            });
            indexSearchResult.setListOfIndexes(searchResults);
            log.info("searchResultsHits {}", searchResults.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("search :: Search on clg flat index. {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return indexSearchResult;
    }
```

So if the limit from 99550 and size 500 then it will not fetch more that 1L records.

```
Error: "reason" : "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [100000] but was [100050]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."
        }
```

I don't want to change [index.max_result_window]. Only want solution at Java side to search all docs in index based on conditions by implementing elasticserach API.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to use _scroll api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html

Comment: I am new in elastic implementation at java side. So can you help me to implement scroll API as well at Java side?